# Why a consistent backup still requery recovery in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, rman

My database was in mount state and we perfomed a backup of the database.

```
backup database format '/backup/db_full%U.bkp';
```

So, when restoring it, I can't simple use:

```
Restore database;
alter database open;
```

It shows

```
SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 1: '+DATA/orcl/datafile/system.257.1161421855'
```

Why do I still need to recovery the database? I know that when the database is open and we perform some backup, we must recover because the backup was inconsistent, but in this case the database was in mount state when the backup as performed. I don't want to recover because I don't want to apply all changes after backup.

**Edit:**
I've found the backup option "consistent" in Oracle 19c documentation.

```
backup consistent database format '/backup/db_full%U.bkp';
```

but still requery recovery (and the backup was performed in mount state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to restore cold backup of database taken using Rman (Doc ID 1391384.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1391384.1)

Summary of steps:

```
Step 1 :- Startup Nomount the database
Step 2 :- Restore controlfile from the backuppiece.
Step 3 :- Mount the database
Step 4 :- Restore database
Step 5 :- Open the database with resetlogs
```

If you do not restore (Step 2) the controlfile from the backup that was taken with the offline backup and use the current/latest controlfile, you get the error you got.

Alternatively, you can recreate the controlfile manually (with the `CREATE CONTROLFILE` statement) after which `alter database open resetlogs;` also works, without the need for recovery.